# How to delete a Server from SCCM from local PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, server, scripting, sccm

I have a PowerShell script on my local computer/laptop that I am using to automate a procedure. One component of that procedure is to remove a server from SCCM. SCCM is on a remote server.
Is there a way that I can remove it through the script? Previously, when trying to do so, I would get an error saying that I cannot remove SCCM from command line, so maybe there is a way I can overcome this from a permissions perspective? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to remove an SCCM agent/node, an SCCM Site server, or just uninstall SCCM? Are there other SCCM servers in your environment? What SCCM Roles are installed on this server? You say you tried via command line - what command, and what error did you get? Please add *all* of this to your question.